# How to disable a view generated shadow when being pushed / popped on iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In my app, I have a clear background color set because I have a view that I am animating as a background.

So when pushing a view(on iOS 7), Apple generates a drop shadow on the view closest to the right (see image)

I am attempting to navigate between 2-3 views and since I have a clear background color, it generates an unnecessary shadow

is there any clean solution to disable this generated drop shadow?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the push/pop viewcontroller with animation = NO and put this code on the viewDidAppear of the viewController that you are pushing:

> ```
> [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 
>                  animations:^{
>                      self.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480);
>                  }];
> ```

And this, when you pop the viewController:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
                 }];
```